# datagridview disable user moving through/selecting cells/rows

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

i have a datagridview.

I have two buttons, "previous" and "next" which programmatically selects the prev/next row.

My problem: Right now, if user clicks on a row/cell, the selected row changes and same if he uses keyboard arrows etc.

I want to **disable** any ways of browsing-selecting rows from user clicks/keypresses, so browsing of the datagridview contents will be only by using the "previous" and "next" buttons.

**Important: User must be able to use the horizontal/vertical scrollbars.**

How to achieve this? Capturing all clicking events and keystrokes? There must be an easier way!

(There are no row headers, no cell headers)

Comment: my current solution is `datagridview` `Enabled=False` and external `VerticalScrollBar` and `HorizontalScrollBar` which programmatically are synced with the `datagridview` control. I'm leaving the question open in case a "native" `datagridview` solution arises.